# How do I drop and change dtype in a Pipeline with sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I have some scraped data that needs some cleaning. After the cleaning, I want to create a "numerical and categorical pipelines" inside a ColumnTransformer such as:

```
categorical_cols = df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns
numerical_cols = df.select_dtypes(exclude='object').columns

num_pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())
    ]
)

cat_pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('onehotencoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
    ]
)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer([
    ('num_pipeline', num_pipeline, numerical_cols),
    ('cat_pipeline', cat_pipeline, categorical_cols)
])
```

My idea was to create a transformer `class Transformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):` and create a pipeline with it. That transformer would include all the cleaning steps. My problem is that some of the steps change the dtype from object to integer mostly so I'm thinking that instead of defining the categorical_cols and numerical_cols with dtypes, instead, do it with column names.

Would that be the correct approach? The idea would be to automate the process so I can train the model with new data every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making a list of columns beforehand you can use scikit-learn's [`make_column_selector`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_selector.html#sklearn.compose.make_column_selector) to dynamically specify the columns that each transformer will be applied to.

In your example:

```py
from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector as selector

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer([
    ('num_pipeline', num_pipeline, selector(dtype_exclude=object)),
    ('cat_pipeline', cat_pipeline, selector(dtype_include=object))
])
```

Under the hood it uses pandas' [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html#pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes) for the type selection. You can pass a regex and select based on column name as well.

I also recommend you checking out [`make_column_transformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer.html#sklearn.compose.make_column_transformer) for more control over the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

the process is OK, as you said the type changes, and on many occasions, you `encode` the data to use it. To prevent this from happening label columns as `categorical` and `numerical` then change their types as you wish; for example use `LabelEncoder`. in many situations, a missing value makes an `integer` column into an `object` making you miserable in reporting results.
so forget about total automation in this field and try methods to get each columns `dtype` and save them, then give the data to the `pipeline`.

```
# Define numerical and categorical columns
numerical_cols = ['numerical_col_1', 'numerical_col_2', ...]
categorical_cols = ['categorical_col_1', 'categorical_col_2', ...]

num_pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[        ('scaler', StandardScaler())    ]
)

cat_pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[        ('onehotencoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))    ]
)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer([    ('num_pipeline', num_pipeline, numerical_cols),    ('cat_pipeline', cat_pipeline, categorical_cols)])
```

With this modification, you can update the `numerical_cols` and `categorical_cols` lists whenever you have new data with different columns, and the pipeline will adapt accordingly.

you can always do this methods and methods like this to find each columns `dtype`.

```
non_integer_columns = []
new_data = data.dropna()
for col in data.columns:
   try:
      new_data[col] = new_data[col].astype(int)
   except:
     non_integer_columns.append(col)
```